# javascript determine which OR statement triggered if statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a condition like this (this is much simplified, they are actually events):

```
if(!a || !b || !c || !d){
  //do something with 1,b,c, or d
}
```

how do I determine which var triggered the if? Doing if(a) else if(b) is not really a good option here as it will result in a lot of repeated code.

Comment: Do you need just one var, or do you need to act on all vars for which `!var` is true? If `!a` is true but so is `!c`, do you need both?

Comment: What are you trying to simplify this way? Why will `if(a) else if(b)` result in a lot of repeated code?

Comment: There is no `or` operator in JS.

Comment: Typo on my part. I need to do something with all the ones that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try with a function that returns the index of the first true condition, or -1 if all conditions are false:

```
var conditions = [];

conditions.push(a);
conditions.push(b);
conditions.push(c);
conditions.push(d);
// ...

var triggerer = (function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++){
        if(conditions[i]){ return i; };
    }
    return -1;
})();

if(triggerer != -1){
    // Do something with conditions[triggerer]
}else{
    // Do something when everything is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your conditions in an array and check them in a loop:

```
var values = [a, b, c, d];
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(!values[i]) {
        //...
        // `values[i]` is the *first* condition that satisfies the `if` statement.
        break;
    }
}
```